# Most concise method of writing object field values to System.out in Java

Tags: java, debugging

What's the most concise method of logging a large number of field values? Ex, say you have 6 fields you want to output the values of, all int types at a given line.

The most obvious solution is to do something like this:

```
System.out.println("renderMap() xTile: " + xTile + "  yTile: " + yTile + 
    "  maxXTile: " + maxXTile + "  maxYTile: " + maxYTile + "  xPixelOffset: " + 
    xPixelOffset + "  yPixelOffset: " + yPixelOffset);
```

Is there a more concise and *less painful* method of doing this in Java, if you're making lots of changes that consistently requires you to write debugging lines such as the above?

I accept that what I did above might just be the most concise syntax, but a confirmation (or rebuttal) of that would be nice.

**I ended up doing this as a solution (a bit less than my requirements above but I'll live with it):**

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d %d  %d %d  %d %d", xTile, yTile, 
    maxXTile, maxYTile, xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset));
```

Comment: Override toString() so that you construct such a string only once. This is with assumption that you would want to display field/property values from the class.

Comment: Tried to keep the question itself short for readability, but to preempt a few questions or suggestions I've already tried: I thought about doing this in a utility method, using reflection you can grab the class/method name, attribute names/values, but that solution get increasingly complex once you start dealing with variables that are scoped to a method or a code block such as a for loop int.  Also, simply overriding toString for the object just isn't flexible enough.

Comment: @Sudhanshu You beat me to my addition. :) Thought about that, but what if the variable is something like a for loop counter variable? Anything not scoped at the Class level isn't going to be accessible to toString().

Answer (score 0):

Make a format string and use String.format(formatstring, object.value1, object.value2, ...) with it. This is not much less concise, but it looks MUCH neater, as instead of the variables and the string's structure being intermingled, you describe entirely the format of what you want, then entirely the values you will place in it. If you've ever used printf in C, it's very similar.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

This doesn't apply to Java (unless you can do a trick with Reflection?) but in languages like Python, where all objects secretly have hashmaps of variable names to values, you could iterate over this hashmap and automatically construct a debugging string of all its variable names and values.

Comment: Oh believe me, I'm dying for a major Java language update from Oracle which adds some Python or ActionScript (you can also do this in Flash) features to the language, but I doubt it'll ever happen! But this is a good idea to try.

Comment: Funny, I've been a Java dev for almost 10 years and I either forgot about or didn't know how sophisticated String.format() is.